# How to hide format option from that menu

Tags: permissions, nautilus, filesystem, users

How to hide or put a password on formatting partitions to prevent other users from formatting my data accidentally

[image: desktop screen]

Answer (score 0):

Normally normal users ( non-root ) should be prompted if they want format a disk, are you sure that is not prompted?

More to look in order to restrict/allow users to do something on the server is sudo or policykit-desktop-privileges ( PolicyKit ), otherwise there is more information needed.